# ASP.net StackedColumn Chart Series - Overlapping & Gaps

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, charts, stacked-chart

I'm trying to deploy some charts on my web application, but am having trouble with the StackedColumn chart; the series are either overlapping each other or gapping apart from each other, the result being that the overall total is misrepresented.  Here are two examples showing each problem:

http://sdrv.ms/17nzZ2k - gaps between series

http://sdrv.ms/1fg6LqW - overlapping series

This is my code to generate the chart:

```
Private Sub chartMonMStack_DataBinding(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles chartMonMStack.DataBinding

    Dim chart As Chart = chartMonMStack
    Dim cArea As String = "area"

    chart.ChartAreas(cArea).Position.Width = 85
    chart.ChartAreas(cArea).Position.Height = 100
    chart.ChartAreas(cArea).AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#999999")
    chart.ChartAreas(cArea).AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#999999")
    chart.ChartAreas(cArea).AxisX.Title = "年"
    chart.ChartAreas(cArea).AxisY.Title = "NTD"
    chart.ChartAreas(cArea).AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "#,##0"

    Dim conStr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("GenshenPOS").ConnectionString
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection(conStr)

    conn.Open()

    Dim sql As String = "SELECT [y], [Store], SUM([amount]) AS [NTD] FROM vwMonthly " & _
                        "WHERE [m] = '" & dropMonth.SelectedValue & "月' GROUP BY [y], [Store] ORDER BY [y], [Store]"

    Dim sqlPoints As New SqlCommand(sql, conn)

    Dim reader As SqlDataReader = sqlPoints.ExecuteReader()

    While reader.Read()

        If chart.Series.IndexOf(reader.Item("Store")) = -1 Then

            chart.Series.Add(reader.Item("Store"))
            chart.Legends.Add(reader.Item("Store"))
            chart.Series(reader.Item("Store")).ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn
            chart.Series(reader.Item("Store")).ChartArea = cArea
            chart.Series(reader.Item("Store")).IsValueShownAsLabel = True
            chart.Series(reader.Item("Store")).LabelFormat = "#,##0"
            chart.Series(reader.Item("Store")).LabelForeColor = Drawing.Color.White

        End If

        chart.Series(reader.Item("Store")).Points.AddXY(reader.Item("y"), reader.Item("NTD"))

    End While

    conn.Close()

End Sub
```

I've read that the gaps can occur because of missing data if the series has a blank data point, however on the affected column, there are no missing data points.  Additionally I don't think this can explain why in other instances, the bars overlap and do not position themselves on the chart correctly.  Nevertheless I tried adding the following but to no avail.

```
For Each s As Series In chart.Series
    chart.DataManipulator.InsertEmptyPoints(1, IntervalType.Number, s)
Next
```

If anyone can help I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that `InsertEmptyPoints` was the correct method for resolving the problem, however if anyone has issues with this not appearing to do anything as I did, then using additional parameters in the method could resolve your issue, as it did mine.

```
For Each s As Series In chart.Series
    chart.DataManipulator.InsertEmptyPoints(1, IntervalType.Number, 0, IntervalType.Number, MinXAxis, MaxXAxis, s)
Next
```

I used a 0 value in the offset section of the method (as I have no need to offset), and instead focused on the 5th (`fromXValue`) and 6th (`toXValue`) parameters to specify the range of values along my axis.  The variables MinXAxis and MaxXAxis are assigned the values I need dynamically.

This resolves both the gapping and overlap for my series.

For more info on `InsertEmptyPoints` see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456677%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), however be advised it currently makes no mention of the `fromXValue` and `toXValue` parameters, I found out about them from within Visual Studio.